# Nonvisual error handler for Yii2 API services

Tags: php, rest, error-handling, yii2

I am developing web API services in Yii2, I expect that my Yii2 application will be used by other programs (e.g. by React SPA application that is hosted in other domain/application) and not by the human end-user. So, I don't need Yii2 default error handling page (which is enabled by default in the debug mode) which displays in human readable form the stack trace. Instead, I need to return any error information in the API manner, e.g., as machine readable, structured JSON response.

That is why I have tried the code:
I have configuration in config/web.php:

```
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
],
```

and I have SiteController.php action:

```
 public function actionError() {
        $exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler;
        return json_encode($exception);
    }
```

and I have exception raising code in other action:

```
 public function actionTest() {
    $test = [];
    $test1 = $test['form_id']; //Exception Undefined index: form_id  
    return 'OK';
}
```

by my actionError displays error:

```
{
    "maxSourceLines": 19,
    "maxTraceSourceLines": 13,
    "errorAction": "site\/error",
    "errorView": "@yii\/views\/errorHandler\/error.php",
    "exceptionView": "@yii\/views\/errorHandler\/exception.php",
    "callStackItemView": "@yii\/views\/errorHandler\/callStackItem.php",
    "previousExceptionView": "@yii\/views\/errorHandler\/previousException.php",
    "displayVars": ["_GET", "_POST", "_FILES", "_COOKIE", "_SESSION"],
    "traceLine": "{html}",
    "discardExistingOutput": true,
    "memoryReserveSize": 262144,
    "exception": {}
}
```

So, the problem is, that this is very uninformative message, there is no error code, no error description, no stack trace, nothing worth for the other application, apparently `exception` structure is empty. How can I get some error information in my SiteController.actionError for converting it into the technical message that can be consumed by API customers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to implement own error action to generate responses with different format. The default error action adjust the output based on `Yii::$app->response->format`.

```
public function actionMyAction()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    throw new \yii\base\Exception('test');
}
```

This code will generate json output like this:

```
{
  "name":"Exception",
  "message": "test",
  "code":0,
  "type":"yii\\base\\Exception",
  "file":"D:\\path\\to\\controllers\\TestController.php",
  "line":20,
  "stack-trace":
  [
    ...
  ]
}
```

[More info about error handling](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-handling-errors#error-format)